# Calculate PMI values using a given context window

Tags: python, similarity

Given the following basis:

```
basis = "Each word of the text is converted as follows: move any consonant (or consonant cluster) that appears at the start of the word to the end, then append ay."
```

and the following words:

```
words = "word, text, bank, tree"
```

How can I calculate the PMI-values of each word in "words" compared to each word in "basis", where I can use a context window size 5 (that is two positions before and two after the target word)?

I know how to calculate the PMI, but I don't know how to handle the fact of the context window.

I calculate the 'normal' PMI-values as follows:

```
def PMI(ContingencyTable):
    (a,b,c,d,N) = ContingencyTable
    # avoid log(0)
    a += 1
    b += 1
    c += 1
    d += 1
    N += 4

    R_1 = a + b
    C_1 = a + c

    return log(float(a)/(float(R_1)*float(C_1))*float(N),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little searching on PMI, looks like heavy duty packages are out there, "windowing" included

In [PMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information) the "mutual" seems to refer to the joint probability of two different words so you need to firm up that idea with respect to the problem statement

I took on the smaller problem of just generating the short windowed lists in your problem statement mostly for my own exercise

```
def wndw(wrd_l, m_l, pre, post):
    """
    returns a list of all lists of sequential words in input wrd_l
    that are within range -pre and +post of any word in wrd_l that matches
    a word in m_l

    wrd_l      = list of words
    m_l        = list of words to match on
    pre, post  = ints giving range of indices to include in window size      
    """
    wndw_l = list()
    for i, w in enumerate(wrd_l):
        if w in m_l:
           wndw_l.append([wrd_l[i + k] for k in range(-pre, post + 1)
                                           if 0 <= (i + k ) < len(wrd_l)])
    return wndw_l

basis = """Each word of the text is converted as follows: move any
             consonant (or consonant cluster) that appears at the start
             of the word to the end, then append ay."""

words = "word, text, bank, tree"

print(*wndw(basis.split(), [x.strip() for x in words.split(',')], 2, 2),
      sep="\n")
['Each', 'word', 'of', 'the']
['of', 'the', 'text', 'is', 'converted']
['of', 'the', 'word', 'to', 'the']
```